# Copy Database to /data in Android Device

Tags: java, android, sqlite, root, adb

Okay, I tried many thing to make my apps can access database using SQLite on my phone. I create an LBS apps, and all Location saved in dbtaxi. I pull dbtaxi from my android emulator and I want to copy it to /data on my phone using adb. as I expected, I need to be a root.

Is there any way to put it without become a root first ? Or any other way to make sure, my apps can access it on my phone.

Help me please.

Comment: do you need this only for testing?

Comment: No. I tried to copy it to /data/data/"package name"/ but it failed and need root access on my phone.

Comment: why cant you generate your data on again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to put it without become a root first ?

No.

> Or any other way to make sure, my apps can access it on my phone.

Your app should be creating and populating its own database. After all, assuming there are more than a couple of users in your home, you will not be able to manually copy a database to all your users' phones.

You might try https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper as a way to package your database inside your app to deploy to devices.